# Integrating uiautomator test case with application code in Android

Tags: java, android, android-testing, android-uiautomator

I am using Eclipse IDE.
Here is my code for uiautomator testcase:

```
public class caltest extends UiAutomatorTestCase {

    public void testDemo() throws UiObjectNotFoundException, IOException {

    //mytesstcode

    }
}
```

To run this test i have to issue following commands from command line:

1. /tools/android create uitest-project -n  -t 1 -p
2. Go to the project directory where your build.xml file is located and build your test JAR.
   ---> ant build
3. Deploy your generated test JAR file to the test device by using the adb push command:
   ---> adb push  /data/local/tmp/
4. ---> adb shell uiautomator runtest jarname.jar -c caltest

Is there any way i can run my test without using commandline i.e. from the eclipse ide or from within an android application.

Comment: I cannot think of how to do that unless you plan to write another java program and execute it in Eclipse to do item 3 and 4...

Answer (score 2):

Not currently. What I did to simplify the process was to write a bash script.

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash -xe
ant clean build

adb push bin/AutomatedTests.jar /data/local/tmp/

adb shell uiautomator runtest /data/local/tmp/AutomatedTests.jar -c com.example.tests.SimpleTest
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check [Uiautomator-bot](http://sourceforge.net/projects/uiautomator/), it does what you are looking for. You don't have to use any command line. It can also run test cases on multiple devices simultaneously. For more info check this [link](http://uiautomator-bot.blogspot.in/).

Comment: Hi Syed.  Will you have a MAC version of the Uiautomator-bot in the future?