# how to start "uiautomator test run" from android code?

Tags: android, shell, ui-automation, robotium, android-uiautomator

Reference Links:  [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15129125/integrating-uiautomator-test-case-with-application-code-in-android), [Robotium Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14339216/how-to-start-instrumentation-project-programmatically-using-android-intent/14372897#14372897)

as we know that from [Robotium Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14339216/how-to-start-instrumentation-project-programmatically-using-android-intent/14372897#14372897), we can run robotium test run from android code.

Now lets talk about [uiautomator](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/uiautomator/index.html)

i already done following steps manually from [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15129125/integrating-uiautomator-test-case-with-application-code-in-android)

```
adb push bin/AutomatedTests.jar /data/local/tmp/
```

Question : How to run bellow line from "Android Activity Code" :

```
adb shell uiautomator runtest /data/local/tmp/AutomatedTests.jar -c com.example.tests.SimpleTest
```

Case 1:

i tried this code: [Code Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15607710/how-to-top-m-10-n-1-command-output-save-to-string-in-android-code), with arguments as bellow

```
String[] strCmdArgsUiTesting = 
"/system/bin/uiautomator runtest UiTestingExample.jar -c com.intel.vishal.uitestingexample.LaunchBasemarkES2Taiji".split(" ");
```

Error comes :

```
INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: longMsg=Permission Denial: 
Do not have permission in call getContentProviderExternal() 
from pid=2691, uid=10082 
requires android.permission.ACCESS_CONTENT_PROVIDERS_EXTERNALLY
```

i added this permission to AndroidManifest.xml as bellow

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_CONTENT_PROVIDERS_EXTERNALLY"/>
```

but same error comes again. this permission is not working in android activity...

How to solve this error ?

Please Note :-
i am using Android 4.2.2

Comment: were you able to solve this problem? I'm stuck on this as well.

Comment: Were you able to do this? I'm stuck on the same thing. I'm stuck on a rooted device as well. :-(

Comment: i am not able to do this, as android application does not have permission to access "uiautomator runtest". i have signed my android test application & using robotium i am accessing UI of my test app & that will do automation for only one application. [ not complete system ].

Answer (score 3):

I do believe that your phone needs to be **rooted** in order to call any console command from the app's Java code...

Comment: yes friend, rooting is last option for me, i will try it & let you know in next 2 weeks, thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Check this link to see how to run a command from android code: [Android run bash command in app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7543700/android-run-bash-command-in-app)

Now, you want to execute

```
uiautomator runtest /data/local/tmp/AutomatedTests.jar -c com.example.tests.SimpleTest
```

instead of

```
adb shell uiautomator runtest /data/local/tmp/AutomatedTests.jar -c com.example.tests.SimpleTest
```

Comment: i tried to execute from this link "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15607710/how-to-top-m-10-n-1-command-output-save-to-string-in-android-code", but error is "INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: longMsg=Permission Denial: Do not have permission in call getContentProviderExternal() from pid=2691, uid=10082 requires android.permission.ACCESS_CONTENT_PROVIDERS_EXTERNALLY", how to solve this ?

Comment: see this link for some information, "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18137176/android-workaround-the-access-content-providers-externally-permission" about my error

Comment: if you are getting an error related to permission, simply add <uses-permission> tag in the manifest file and use the permission android.permission.ACCESS_CONTENT_PROVIDERS_EXTERNALLY

Comment: i already added same permission, but same error comes again. this permission is not working.

Comment: newers android newest permission and newer protection....
simple solutions : root :: danger.